# what is the less complex way to have two React components connected to communicate and share data?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

I am facing a use case that could have already found answers on stackoverflow so feel free to share topics that might answer my question. I searched and didn't find what I need. Thank you.

I want to know how can I get a React component affected by another writing as minimum code as possible to get those two components communicate.

Here is my use case:

- The project I work on use Redux to share data though components
- I include in the project a react node module component that offers callbacks to self event and supply his current state info: [ReactGridLayout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) in my case.
- I want to create a react component able to monitor changes in [ReactGridLayout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) and displays it on the screen. Lets call this component `ReactGridLayoutMonitor`.
- `ReactGridLayoutMonitor` could be shared on github so I want anyone able to use it and integrate it easily. I could have create a redux reducer to save data from [ReactGridLayout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) and to connect it to `ReactGridLayoutMonitor` but it will not be usable for people that doesn't want or can't use Flux architecture.

How can I offer an easy-to-use `ReactGridLayoutMonitor` that will require small work for people who want to use it with [ReactGridLayout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout)?

Here is a small graph of what i try to do:
[image]

My idea is to create a global variable `RGLDdata` and to wrap [ReactGridLayout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) with a function that will connect [ReactGridLayout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) callbacks to save data in `RGLDdata`. Then `ReactGridLayoutMonitor` will be able to read data in it. 
Is there any other way?

Comment: This is a typical use-case for Redux. As I see you are already using it, why have you chosen not to use it here ? is it a problem of reusability for other users ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to offer ReactGridLayoutMonitor without forcing developers to use Redux. I want to provide an easy-to-integrate component

Comment: Is it not a fair use constraint to say that the `ReactGridLayoutMonitor` must wrap a `ReactGridLayout`? That's probably what I would expect.

Comment: That's what I did at the begining but It means displaying `ReactGridLayoutMonitor` and `ReactGridLayout` at the same position

Answer (score 0):

May be the only solution is to offer a custom reducer and a custom [HOC](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775) to connect this reducer to both `ReactGridLayout` & `ReactGridLayoutMonitor`.

That means for user to integrate the reducer within combineReducer and to wrap `ReactGridLayout` & `ReactGridLayoutMonitor` before using it.

What people here think of that? Any better idea is welcome :)